# Comparing values separated by a special characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 columns, let's say `COLA` and `COLB`, and data as follows:

```
COLA              | COLB
------------------+------------------
PLATE|SPOON|GLASS | PLATE|GLASS|SPOON
PLATE             | SPOON
OIL|JUG|MAT       | JUG|MAT
SPOON             | SPOON
OIL|MAT           | MAT|OIL
```

I'm trying to return non-matching rows irrespective of order.

**Expected output:**

```
COLA        | COLB
------------+--------
PLATE       | SPOON
OIL|JUG|MAT | JUG|MAT
```

I have tried something like below and so many things but not working. I don't have much knowledge on SQL part:

```
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE COLA NOT LIKE '%COLB%'
```

Comment: You mentioned that you don't have much background with SQL.  As it turns out, your current data model, which is storing pipe-delimited values in each cell, is not desirable for so many reasons.  You should ideally get each value onto a separate row/record.  I can't even venture an answer to your current question, but it would be very ugly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , Unfortunately i don't have any access to change the data model :( I will take this suggestion to the higher level. But for now if you could give me some way to achieve this , it would be great.

Comment: Does your table have an ID column of some kind? This will be very difficult if not

Comment: Do you have a string_split function available to you? The solution is much easier to get to with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `CROSS APPLY` to cast the 2 strings as XML type.

And then the node values of those XML's can be compared in an `EXISTS` clause.

**Sample Data:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE YourTable
> (
>   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>   ColA NVARCHAR(100),
>   ColB NVARCHAR(100)
> );
> INSERT INTO YourTable (ColA, ColB) VALUES
>   ('PLATE|SPOON|GLASS', 'PLATE|GLASS|SPOON')
> , ('PLATE',             'SPOON')
> , ('OIL|JUG|MAT',       'JUG|MAT')
> , ('SPOON',             'SPOON')
> , ('OIL|MAT',           'MAT|OIL');
> GO
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT t.*
> FROM YourTable t
> CROSS APPLY 
> (
>   SELECT 
>   CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(t.ColA,'|','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS XML) AS XmlA,
>   CAST('<b>'+REPLACE(t.ColB,'|','</b><b>')+'</b>' AS XML) AS XmlB
> ) caX
> WHERE EXISTS
> (
>   SELECT 1
>   FROM
>   (
>     (
>       SELECT a.val.value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS val
>       FROM caX.XmlA.nodes('/a') AS a(val)   
>       EXCEPT
>       SELECT b.val.value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS val
>       FROM caX.XmlB.nodes('/b') AS b(val)
>     )
>     UNION ALL
>     (
>       SELECT b.val.value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS val
>       FROM caX.XmlB.nodes('/b') AS b(val)
>       EXCEPT
>       SELECT a.val.value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS val
>       FROM caX.XmlA.nodes('/a') AS a(val)   
>     )
>   ) q
> );
> ```

**Result:**

> ```
> ID | ColA        | ColB   
> -: | :---------- | :------
>  2 | PLATE       | SPOON  
>  3 | OIL|JUG|MAT | JUG|MAT
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3ddc03d3e79a808c146297996d1ce109)*

**Extra:**

In Sql Server 2016 and beyond, the STRING_SPLIT function is available.
So then this shorter alternative would work:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(ColA,'|') a
  FULL JOIN STRING_SPLIT(ColB,'|') b
    ON a.value = b.value
  WHERE a.value IS NULL
     OR b.value IS NULL
);
```

Comment: Wow. This looks so simple. Thanks you so much. Though I'm having bit of trouble to understand the XML and nodes, it solved my problem. I will explore to get the knowledge on this.

Comment: If you ever upgrade, the extra solution could be used.

Comment: The extra solution seems to be more simpler than the earlier one. Thanks for that too. Looking at this , I guess there are quite a lot of difference between `2012` & `2016` version. We will definitely have to plan the upgrade very soon then.

Comment: @Omega They have a 2019 version already. But skip 2016.  The 2017 version has some usefull stuff, f.e. [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

One method is a recursive subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), null) as parta,
             convert(varchar(max), cola) as resta,
             cola, colb,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
      union all
      select convert(varchar(max),
                     left(resta, charindex('|', resta + '|') - 1)
                    ) as parta,
             convert(varchar(max),
                     stuff(resta, 1, charindex('|', resta + '|'), '')
                    ) as resta,
             cola, colb, seqnum
      from cte
      where resta <> ''
     )
select cola, colb
from cte
where parta is not null
group by seqnum, cola, colb
having sum(case when concat('|', colb, '|') like concat('%|', parta, '|%') then 1 else 0 end) <> count(*) or
       len(cola) <> len(colb);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=976fc93108cee8b9e455ffdad61071eb) is a db<>fiddle.

This is much simpler in more recent versions of SQL Server that support string splitting and aggregation.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot @Gordan Linoff for the solution. We are having the plan to upgrade SQL server shortly. Hopefully we will finish it up soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user defined function to split the delimited strings in each column and then compare the results of that function.

I've chosen to use one of the fastest string-split functions for SQL Server (prior to 2016 where it has a built in string split) - Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K. You can read all about it in his article called [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (
    ColA varchar(100),
    ColB varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @T (ColA, ColB) VALUES
('PLATE|SPOON|GLASS', 'PLATE|GLASS|SPOON'),
('PLATE', 'SPOON'),
('OIL|JUG|MAT', 'JUG|MAT'),
('SPOON', 'SPOON'),
('OIL|MAT', 'MAT|OIL');
```

The query:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB
FROM @T
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](ColA, '|')
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](ColB, '|')
)
OR 
 EXISTS (
    SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](ColB, '|')
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](ColA, '|')
)
```

Results:

```
ColA            ColB
PLATE           SPOON
OIL|JUG|MAT     JUG|MAT
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/KSBKNR23334)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zohar Peled. Right now, I don't have access to create this function. I will request for the access and try this out and i'm sure this will be the easiest one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method which relies on splitting comma sep strings into rows using xml functions. Then comparing the values in the cola and colb and returing the differences

```
with data2
  as (select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rnk ,cola,colb
        from t 
      )
  ,combo_data
  as(
   SELECT a.rnk 
          ,a.cola
          ,a.colb
          ,Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)') AS Data
          ,1 as a_flag
          ,null as b_flag
    FROM ( SELECT rnk
                  ,cola
                  ,colb
                  ,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(cola, '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
            FROM data2    
          ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
   union all
   SELECT a.rnk 
          ,a.cola
          ,a.colb
          ,Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)') AS Data 
          ,null as a_flag
          ,1 as b_flag
    FROM ( SELECT rnk
                  ,cola
                  ,colb
                  ,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(colb, '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
            FROM data2    
          ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
    )
    select rnk,cola,colb,data,count(a_flag) as present_in_cola,count(b_flag) as present_in_colb
      from combo_data
      group by rnk,cola,colb,data
      having count(a_flag) <> count(b_flag)
      order by 1,2,3,4


+-----+-------------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
| rnk |    cola     |  colb   | data  | present_in_cola | present_in_colb |
+-----+-------------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
|   2 | PLATE       | SPOON   | PLATE |               1 |               0 |
|   2 | PLATE       | SPOON   | SPOON |               0 |               1 |
|   3 | OIL|JUG|MAT | JUG|MAT | OIL   |               1 |               0 |
+-----+-------------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c677e8628d2734305f2b7f1923e583b

Comment: Thanks for your effort. however it is giving me more rows than expected.

Comment: Yes it will give you the differences so specifically it will give the values of cola which are not present in colb and vice versa. If you do not want that then you may remove the "data" column from group by and the select clause